# Memory access violation error c++

Tags: c++, memory-access

I'm trying to exchange messages using multiple covert channels.
So, basically, first i need to select the channel that i want to use for communication and then select the "destination_ip" of the user that i want to chat with and after that the

> processMessage()

is called. Now, to move from one channel to another I have to close the existing connection and then open a new connection with the new channel that i want to use. My code below is modified to keep using the same channel after closing the connection and contain only the things that you need.

```
#include <channelmanager.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

struct CommunicationFixture {
    CommunicationFixture() {
        channelmanager.setErrorStream(&cout);
        channelmanager.setOutputStream(&cout);
        destination_ip = "";
        channel_id = channelmanager.getChannelIDs()[0];

    }
    library::ChannelManager channelmanager;
    vector<string> last_adapters;
    string destination_ip;
    string channel_id = "";


    int processMessage(string message) {
        if (message.compare("exit") == 0) {
            channelmanager.closeConnection(destination_ip);
            return 1;
        }
        vector<string> arguments;
        boost::split(arguments, message, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);
        if (arguments[0].compare("argument") == 0) {
            if (arguments.size() < 2) {
                cout << "Not enough arguments" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            string argument_list = arguments[1];
            for (unsigned int i = 2; i < arguments.size(); i++) {
                argument_list += " " + arguments[i];
            }
            channelmanager.setChannelArguments(destination_ip, argument_list);
            cout << "Set channel argument to '" << argument_list << "'." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        if (message.compare("help") == 0) {
            cout << "Help not available in chat mode. Close chat first with 'exit'" << endl;
            return 0;
        }


        channelmanager.openConnection(destination_ip, channel_id);
        channelmanager.sendMessage(destination_ip, message);

        return 0;

    }

    int close(string destination){
        cout << "closing.." << endl;
        channelmanager.closeConnection(destination); //I believe i have the error because of this!
        return 0;
    }

};


BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(communication, CommunicationFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(basic_communication) {

    selectAdapterId(0);
    cout << "Test" << endl << endl;
    printCommands();
    cout << "Enter your command:" << endl;
    string command;
    int code = 0;
    while (code != 2) {
        std::getline(cin, command);
        code = processCommand(command);
        if (code == 1) {
            // chat
            cout << "chat started.." << endl;
            int chatCode = 0;


            while (chatCode != 1) {
                std::getline(cin, message);
                close(destination_ip);
                chatCode = processMessage(message);
                channelmanager.setErrorStream(&cout);
            }
            cout << "chat ended." << endl;
        }
    }



}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Note that, i think that the error happens due to the

> function close()

because without it i don't get any errors. and the error doesn't happen immediately but after exchanging some messages. Here's the error:

> unknown location(0): fatal error: in
>   "communication/basic_communication": memory access violation at
>   address: 0x00000024: no mapping at fault address
>   communicationTest.cpp(325): last checkpoint: "basic_communication"
>   test entry

Comment: Automatic tests usually don't interact with a user.

Comment: @molbdnilo because a new connection is opened immediately after closing the connection since i call the processMessage() after the close(). And note that the code works fine for like 1 minute and then it crashes.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Load up your debugger!

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Memory access violation happen when you are trying to access to an unitialized variable, in this case the `channelmanager`.

I can only see that you initialize `channelmanager` in the `processMessage()` method and you are closing the connection before initializing the `channelmanager` as it happen in:

```
close(destination_ip);
chatCode = processMessage(message);
```

Either you change the initialization or do not close it before the `processMessage()` method.

Comment: Even if i don't call `close()` and use `channelmanager.closeConnection(destination_ip);` before `channelmanager.openConnection(destination_ip, channel_id);` inside the `processMessage()` function i still get the error!

Comment: There are no initialisations in `processMessage()`. And `channelmanager` looks like a class - you cannot instantiate it without it being initialised, even if that's via the default constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't really understand what you said. And yes channelmanager is a class. So, what should i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Memory access violation is also called a segmentation fault (or segfault), occurs when the program tries to access a memory location that doesn't exist, or is otherwise inaccessible. We call this trying to access an illegal memory location. That memory is either non-existent or we aren't aren't allowed to touch it.

If the first input from user is 'exit', which is going to call

```
if (message.compare("exit") == 0) {
     channelmanager.closeConnection(destination_ip);
     return 1;
}
```

In this case, destination_ip isn't initialised.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's been initialised. Apology for misreading the code.

Comment: destination_ip is initialised too. It's a string. It has a default constructor.

Comment: Yeah, but it's an empty string.

Comment: i edited my question now, but as i said, destination_ip is selected before `processMessage()` is called. So, its not an empty string.

Comment: @ArchieYalakki: An empty string and an uninitialised string are completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

You should initialise `destination_ip` with some empty string.
Check if you have initialised everything to resolve this kind of memory access problems.